# Change Additional product Images based on the selection of color (custom option) Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, media-images, gallery

I want to change the additional images based on the selected color on the product page.

There are many custom options on the product page. My requirement is that, change the additional gallery images based on the selected color.

Please see attached image for further information.

**Note:** This is the simple product having custom options.

[image]

Please guide me how i can do this functionality?
Your help would be appreciated.